# how to get the latest info based on date column and return an object of type BuildMetrics?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I am trying to retrieve SP,Latestbuild(basedon time stamp) and announced date as below,I need guidance on the following

1.How to get the Latest build based on the timestamp in date_announced(format is 2016-12-02 19:24:32)  column in software_product_builds table?I tried as follows but it nots working

```
softwareBuildMetrics.LatestBuild = bitDB.software_product_builds.Where(x => x.software_product_build_id == softwareProductid).Select(x => x.software_product_build).FirstOrDefault();
```

2.How do I return an object of type Build Metrics,I think the current errors are related to this?

```
public class BuildMetrics
{
    public string SP { get; set; }
    public string LatestBuild { get; set; }
    public string AnnouncedDate { get; set; }

}
```

Method:-

```
    public IEnumerable<BuildMetrics> GetBuildMetrics()
    {
        var bitDB = new BitDatabaseConnection().bitDB;
        List<BuildMetrics> softwareBuildMetrics = new List<BuildMetrics>();
         //Get unique list of software product ids
         var softwareProductIds = bitDB.software_products.Select(x => x.id).Distinct().ToList();
        foreach (var softwareProductid in softwareProductIds)
           {
               softwareBuildMetrics.SP = bitDB.software_products.Where(x => x.id == softwareProductid).Select(x => x.software_product).FirstOrDefault();
               softwareBuildMetrics.LatestBuild = bitDB.software_product_builds.Where(x => x.software_product_build_id == softwareProductid).Select(x => x.software_product_build).FirstOrDefault();
               softwareBuildMetrics.AnnouncedDate = bitDB.software_product_builds.Where(x => x.software_product_build_id == softwareProductid).Select(x => x.date_announced).FirstOrDefault();


            }
    }
```

Error:-

```
Error   1   'System.Collections.Generic.List<Dashboard.Model.ApiModels.BuildMetrics>' does not contain a definition for 'SP' and no extension method 'SP' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<Dashboard.Model.ApiModels.BuildMetrics>' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) C:\Users\gnakkala\gnakkala_dashboard\depot\software\projects\user_branches\gnakkala\Dashboard\Dashboard.Data.Repository\BuildRepositories\SoftwareProductRepository.cs  22  41  Dashboard.Data.Repository


Error   2   'System.Collections.Generic.List<Dashboard.Model.ApiModels.BuildMetrics>' does not contain a definition for 'LatestBuild' and no extension method 'LatestBuild' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<Dashboard.Model.ApiModels.BuildMetrics>' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)   C:\Users\gnakkala\gnakkala_dashboard\depot\software\projects\user_branches\gnakkala\Dashboard\Dashboard.Data.Repository\BuildRepositories\SoftwareProductRepository.cs  23  41  Dashboard.Data.Repository

Error   3   'System.Collections.Generic.List<Dashboard.Model.ApiModels.BuildMetrics>' does not contain a definition for 'AnnouncedDate' and no extension method 'AnnouncedDate' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<Dashboard.Model.ApiModels.BuildMetrics>' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)   C:\Users\gnakkala\gnakkala_dashboard\depot\software\projects\user_branches\gnakkala\Dashboard\Dashboard.Data.Repository\BuildRepositories\SoftwareProductRepository.cs  24  41  Dashboard.Data.Repository
```

Comment: What are all these classes-are you using some library?

Comment: what do you mean by what are all these classes?`BuildMetrics` is by Api Model class,now I am trying to write a method retrieving datea from database to fill in the properties of the class?

Comment: You have this line of code: `List<BuildMetrics> softwareBuildMetrics = new List<BuildMetrics>();` That is a generic list of `BuildMetrics`. The `List` type does not have `SP`, `LatestBuild`, and `AnnouncedDate` properties so therefore you are getting that error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

thats not how you add data to the list instead do something like this

```
  foreach (var softwareProductid in softwareProductIds)
           {
               var matric = new BuildMetrics();
               matric.SP = bitDB.software_products.Where(x => x.id == softwareProductid).Select(x => x.software_product).FirstOrDefault();
               matric.LatestBuild = bitDB.software_product_builds.Where(x => x.software_product_build_id == softwareProductid).Select(x => x.software_product_build).FirstOrDefault();
               matric.AnnouncedDate = bitDB.software_product_builds.Where(x => x.software_product_build_id == softwareProductid).Select(x => x.date_announced).FirstOrDefault();
               softwareBuildMetrics.Add(matric);

            }
```

because         `List<BuildMetrics> softwareBuildMetrics = new List<BuildMetrics>();`
means list of `BuildMetrics` objects thats why in above code i created new object of `BuildMetrics` with

```
var matric = new BuildMetrics();
```

and filling in with data and at last i added this object to list with                `softwareBuildMetrics.Add(matric);`

**Edit**

you can use `OrderByDecending` to get latest build

```
softwareBuildMetrics.LatestBuild = bitDB.software_product_builds.Where(x => x.software_product_build_id == softwareProductid).OrderByDescending(x => x.date_announced).Select(x => x.software_product_build).FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: How to get the Latest build based on the timestamp in date_announced(format is 2016-12-02 19:24:32) column in software_product_builds table?

Comment: you mean the last build? or specific build?

Comment: last or latest build?database has a column date_announced which has timestamp of when it was made...need to use it to determine which is the last(latest) build

Comment: you can check now

Comment: got it..Last issue i have is  I get the below error when I return new metric I `Error 3 Cannot implicitly convert type 'Dashboard.Model.ApiModels.BuildMetrics' to 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<Dashboard.Model.ApiM‌​odels.BuildMetrics>'‌​. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)` ,how to convert?

Comment: You should return softwareBuildMerics because its expecting list

Comment: there are no errors now,but somehow `matric.LatestBuild` gives null which is definetely not true..I can see values for it in database?how to debug this?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/137395/discussion-between-usman-and-jeff-short).

Answer (score 0):

You have this line of code:

```
List<BuildMetrics> softwareBuildMetrics = new List<BuildMetrics>();
```

That is a generic list of BuildMetrics. The List type does not have `SP`, `LatestBuild`, and `AnnouncedDate` properties so therefore you are getting that error.

I think what you want to do is this:

```
var newMetric = null;
foreach (var softwareProductid in softwareProductIds)
{
    newMetric = new BuildMetrics();
    newMetric.SP = bitDB.software_products.Where(x => x.id == softwareProductid).Select(x => x.software_product).FirstOrDefault();
    newMetric.LatestBuild = bitDB.software_product_builds.Where(x => x.software_product_build_id == softwareProductid).Select(x => x.software_product_build).FirstOrDefault();
    newMetric.AnnouncedDate = bitDB.software_product_builds.Where(x => x.software_product_build_id == softwareProductid).Select(x => x.date_announced).FirstOrDefault();

    softwareBuildMetrics.Add(newMetric);
}

return softwareBuildMetrics;
```

Comment: Coding Yoshi - When I return new metric I get the error`Error 3 Cannot implicitly convert type 'Dashboard.Model.ApiModels.BuildMetrics' to 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<Dashboard.Model.ApiModels.BuildMetrics>'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)` ,how to convert?

Comment: You need to return `softwareBuildMetrics` not `newMetric`. See edit.